# How to install and configure USB to serial hub (8 serial ports)?

Tags: usb, serial-port

I have bought a USB to serial hub (8 serial ports) but I don't know how I can install it on my Debian server. On the box, they wrote 'Linux compatible'.

What do I need to do to can use it?

Comment: I vaguely recall that serial ports were only scanned at boot time, so if nothing happens when you plug the hub in (check with `dmesg`), you may need to reboot. Typically serial ports should appear as `/dev/ttyS[0-9]` device entries.

Comment: Is there anything else written on the box besides »Linux compatible«?  Like manufacturer or model?

Comment: What happens when you plug it in? In particular, what lines are added to `/var/log/kern.log` (or wherever your distribution puts the kernel logs)? Does the output of `lsusb` change? Do new entries appear in `/dev`?

Comment: Thanks you all for your help. I did not know the "dmesg" command. Thanks you !!